# After ajax request completed do a javascript alert

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsf, commandlink

I have a message page written in jsf and in this page i have a table containing message titles as commandlink. In these commandlinks i have nested ajax to request to my bean to read the message content from db and show it on the page. I tested this functionality by showing the message content in a textearea. But the problem is here that i want to show the content in a javascript alert. So whenever I click the commandlink an alert shows the content of the message. But if I define the javascript method as commandlink onclick attribute then it would run before ajax request and nothing would be shown!
I think we need an attribute that defines a javascript method that would run after ajax request completion. But what's that attribute ?
thanx for any useful answer !

Comment: RTFM: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  "success" option.

Comment: please give me the exact code sample

Comment: You say you've got functionality to show the message in a textarea. showing it in an alert should be an utterly trivial change.

Comment: I am looking for that attribute doing this : do a javascript function after ajax request completion in jsf.

Comment: @MarcB: where did the OP said that he's using jQuery? Shouldn't you RTFQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XHTML

```
<h:commandLink id="button" value="button">
        <f:ajax render="@this" 
            onevent="openPopup"
            listener="#{myBean.getData}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Javascript

```
function openPopup(data){
  if(data.status == "success"){
      // open popup with your message
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

new to XMLHttpRequest? try play around with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="foo" value="load url" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="url" /><br/>
<textarea id="responses"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener("click",function(ev){
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url=document.querySelector("#url").value;
xhr.open("GET",url);
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange",function(ev){
var xhr=ev.target;
if(xhr.readyState<4)return;
document.querySelector("#responses").value+=xhr.responseText;
alert(xhr.responseText);

});
xhr.send();
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with XMLHttpRequest. I am talking about ajax in jsf !